# Manipulate list of character lists in R

Tags: r, list, function, conditional-statements, lapply

I have a `list` of unnamed, comma separated character lists:

```
> list
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

[[2]]
[1] "E" "F" "G"
```

The actual list is long, and each character list inside it is of random length and contains different, unpredictable, character combinations. I need to apply three things to each element of all of the character lists:

- Conditionally *remove* elements, say all those that equal "A"
- Conditionally *replace* elements, say all those that equal "A" with "B"
- If any element contains a "/", e.g. an element equal to "A/BCD", then remove everything to the right of the "/", including the "/" itself, so that I end up with "A" in that particular case.

I am new to R and guess this is a trivial task. I'd be very happy if someone was willing to help me out! Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do any operation on a list, you can use the `apply` family to loop over it. Using `lapply` you get a list back, which is what you want. `lapply` takes the list as a first argument, and then any kind of function you want really.

So let's start from:

```
mylist <- list(
  LETTERS[1:4],
  LETTERS[5:7],
  c("A/BCD","H","J")
)
```

Removing `"A"` in every element of the list goes like this:

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) x[x!="A"])
```

Replacing elements would go like this:

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) {
  id <- x == "B"
  x[id] <- "F"
  return(x)
})
```

Editing the values in each element can be done using `gsub` like this:

```
lapply(mylist, function(x){
  gsub("/.+","",x)
})
```

You can combine everything in one function, and then apply that function to the list. You don't have to create that as an anonymous function inside the `lapply` call, you can predefine it and then use it like this:

```
cleanup <- function(x){
  x <- gsub("/.+","",x) # remove extra info
  id <- x %in% c("A","H")
  x[id] <- "F"
  return(x)
}

lapply(mylist, cleanup)
```

The principle is always the same: each time I create an anonymous function that takes a vector as input and returns the adapted vector as output. `lapply` will make sure these different elements are combined back into a list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just a quick follow up, is there a way to include more conditions at once? for example, replace with "F" everything that includes "B", "C" and so on. I have many conditions and would love to avoid copying that line over and over! Thanks :)

Comment: @CHRD obviously. You just have to adapt the functions accordingly. If you want to check for multiple items in a vector, check `?match` or `%in%`. Inside the function call you can do anything you want with the vector `x`, which represents the elements. I've updated my answer to show the principle of that.